# Asp.Net Core MVC Html.ActionLink not nulling out routevalues

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I'm in the process of converting an Asp.Net MVC 5 project to an Asp Net Core MVC app and I'm pretty close to finishing but I'm noticing that the @Html.ActionLink helper did not port over correctly.

I have a view that uses
 `@Html.ActionLink("Back to " + @action, @action, "SomeController", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })`

What is happening is that, even though I'm passing null as the routeValues parameter, it's keeping the parameter of the current page as the route value.

What am I doing wrong and what's the best way to resolve this?

Comment: Could you please include more codes to help reproduce ?

Comment: @NanYu what additional code are you looking for? The code in the view is pretty straight forward with the Html.ActionLink generating an html button.

Answer (score 1):

For Asp.net core use the following markup

```
<a asp-controller="ControllerName" asp-action="ActionName" asp-route-id="" class="btn btn-success">Link</a>
```

Comment: This created the exact same link the Html.ActionLink helper created.